# Jsoup. Парсинг элемента класс которого начинается на

Tags: java, html, jsoup, парсер

Есть элементы подобные этому:

```
<tr class="trRandom level1 color2" id="event123456" style="display: table-row;">
```

Бывает либо trRandom, либо trRandomChild, а в остальных значениях меняются только лишь цифры. 
Как выбрать элемент класс которого начинается на trRandom средствами библиотеки Jsoup? Можно конечно написать костыли, но не хотелось бы, если есть более деликатный способ решения задачи.

Пробовал код ниже, не помогает.

```
select("[^trRandom]");
select("div[^trRandom]");
```

Остальные способы кидают исключения. Буду благодарен любой подсказке, спасибо!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ваш код:

```
select("[^trRandom]");
select("div[^trRandom]");
```

Производит поиск по названию атрибута, который начинается на `trRandom`, а вам нужно по значению атрибута `class` по такому принципу: `[attr^=valPrefix]`.

Вот так:

```
select("[class^=trRandom]");
select("div[class^=trRandom]");
```

Подробней: http://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/select/Selector.html